# convert a video into frames and then delete some frames

Tags: image, matlab

I wanted to take a video,convert it into different frames and then delete some frames below a threshold value so as to make a new video of the remaining frames.
Can someone help?

Comment: Please add more information to your question, to make clear what you need help with, what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: i am using matlab,i took a video converted into frames now i want to delete some frames below certain threshold value and then again make a video out of remaining frames...i also wanted to know how to put images in loop for processing?? for eg. if i have image1.jpg to image200.jpg and i want to put them in a loop...

Answer (score 1):

To read a video as frames, you can use [`VideoReader()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html):

```
mov = VideoReader(video_file_name);
for i=1:1:mov.numberofframes
    frame=read(mov,i);

    % you got the frame now, do something to the frame...
    % - for your case, check whether the frame is under the threshold or not
end
```

To write frames to a new video, you want to check out [`VideoWriter()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html).